# Как в Unity настроить смешивание текстур из разных GameObject?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Есть 2 текстуры, A и B.

Текстура A перекрывает текстуру B.
На каждой текстуре свой материал и свой шейдер.

В текстуре A хранится картинка, а в текстуре B хранится alpha-маска.

Задача: задать прозрачность текстуре A в зависимости от положения маски B.

Что пиходит в голову: передать в шейдер A купию текстуры B.
Как-то(вот это я не понимаю как) передать вершины текстуры B в шейдер A.
Далее, по идее, координатные преобразования тыры-пыры и все должно сблендиться.

Как передать координаты вершин текстуры gameObject A в шейдер gameObject B???

Comment: Вряд ли вам здесь дадут своевременный ответ по такому вопросу (а именно про особенности _Unity3D_), так что если вам критично найти быстрое решение, то я бы посоветовал, все-таки, попробовать нагуглить что-нибудь :)

Comment: Спасибо. Пробовал гуглить и  сейчас гуглю параллельно) Я верю, что тут есть специалисты)